# Problem with arguments in route function in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to have two arguments in my tabort function but it keeps saying missing 1 required positional argument. I have no idea what to do with it i have two in there but it still saying one is missing. Could anyone help me with this?

```py
@app.route('/tabort/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tabort(id,username):
    """
    Delete the item in the database that matches the specified
    id in the URL
    """
    qry = db_session.query(Matrial).filter(
        Matrial.id==id)
    matrial = qry.first()

    if matrial:
        form = MatrialForm(formdata=request.form, obj=matrial)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            # delete the item from the database
            db_session.delete(matrial)
            db_session.commit()

            flash('Artikel togs bort!')
            return redirect(url_for("user_home", username=username))
        return render_template('tabort_artikel.html', form=form)
    else:
        return 'Något gick fel #{id}'.format(id=id)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\xzenon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: tabort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

Comment: `@app.route('/tabort/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST']) def tabort(id,username):`  The route only provides `id`, where exactly is `username` supposed to come from?

Comment: I put username there to be able to redirect back via this return redirect(url_for("user_home", username=username))

Answer (score 2):

```
@app.route('/tabort/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tabort(id,username):
```

Your path has `<int: id>` in it. So flask will parse an id integer from the path and pass it to your function. But your function is looking for TWO args, id and username, while the router is only passing one. Either remove `username` from your arg list, or add `<username>` to the path somewhere.

Comment: Therefore, is it truly impossible to pass variables between routes without the variable being exposed in the URL? Seems crazy!

Comment: No, you can use a POST or PUT method and have data in the body such as a json or form data. But passing variables _between_ routes- if you dont want it exposed, dont redirect the user. factor the logic into a function and have both routes call that function.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are constructing URL like below:

```py
@app.route('/tabort/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tabort(id,username):
```

The URL is taking only one parameter, but the method needs two parameters, there you are going wrong.

In order to send two parameters to the method, you need to send 2 parameters to the URL also, something like below:

```py
@app.route('/tabort/<int:id>/<string:username', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tabort(id,username):
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: but I put username there to be able to redirect back via this return redirect(url_for("user_home", username=username))

Comment: The methods receives all its parameters from its URL, that you are building with the help of `@app.route()`.

Comment: Ok if i remove the username from the arg list. How can i make this line of code to work return redirect(url_for("user_home", username=username)) without giving me the NameError: name 'username' is not defined error?

Comment: Well.. what is the problem if you pass the username in URL? That would be easy. If you still want to keep the URL same and still use username, then I would suggest that, you need to pass the username in the body of HTTP request. But, this would only work in `POST` request.

Comment: Along with `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH` requests also supports body.

Comment: I dont think you understand me. forget about the @app.route for a moment its not the problem. The problem is you need to be loged in to get to the redirect page redirect(url_for("user_home", username=username)) and thats what the username is for. So either i need the username as an arg like i have been using it true out my code or if there is a way to define it inside the function and get the same results.

Comment: Yes, that's OK, but how and from where will you get the username? Suppose if you have a method `def func(x): x = y` here you can see that `x` is been assigned `y`'s value, but where that `y`'s value is coming from? So, you need to have username's value, that you can get it either from URL, `POST` body or from sessions.